# I can't find documentation on how to iterate across items in two lists serially, just in parallel

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to execute the same effect as the below code, but there has to be a way to do it in one (possibly nested) for loop, right?

list_1 and list_2 have a bunch of numbers. I need to sort the contents into a list for odds and a list for evens. The below works, but seems inelegant. Is there a way to combine the two for loops into one?

```
# parse list_1
for i in list_1:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        list_even.append(i)
    else:
        list_odd.append(i)

# parse list_2
for i in list_2:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        list_even.append(i)
    else:
        list_odd.append(i)
```

Comment: Combine the 2 lists into one.

Comment: `for i in list_1 + list_2: ...`

Comment: Thanks oskros. Exactly what I needed. I was overthinking it.

Comment: @Dave - try the posted one, see if you any question.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try that it much faster and easier no need to write same operation for each list

```
   def anyoperation(i):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            list_even.append(i)
        else:
            list_odd.append(i)
    
    list(map(anyoperation,list_1))
    list(map(anyoperation,list_2))
```